# how to count without duplicates?

Tags: sql, fastreport

i got the below query and i want to count the EAMDATE when EAMATTNSTATUS= 7 or 8 as 0.5 AND Count EAMDATE when EAMATTNSTATUS= 6 as one.

---

```
  SELECT EAMEMID,
           SUM(CASE WHEN EAMATTNSTATUS in (7) OR EAMATTNSTATUS in (8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 2 + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EAMATTNSTATUS in (6) THEN EAMDATE END) as ABSENTDAYS  
    FROM viewDAILYSUM  
    WHERE (EAMEMID = :EAMEMID) AND
          (EAMDATE between :FDate and :TDate)
    GROUP BY EAMEMID                                                                                                     
    ORDER BY EAMEMID
```

---

the difficult part for me, that there this some situation that one EAMDATE could have EAMATTNSTATUS =7 or 8 status AND EAMATTNSTATUS =6. Which means it will duplicate the counting for that EAMDATE twice because it has the 2 status.

how i can fix the duplicate ??

i tried to use Distinct but it didnt work ...

any idea ??!

Thanks

```
SAMPLE DATA 
    EAMEID | EAMDATE | EAMATTNSTATUS| 
    ------ | --------| -------------|
    161    |20/7/2016| 6            | 
    161    |20/7/2016| 7            |   
    161    |21/7/2016| 6            |   
    161    |22/7/2016| 5            |   
    161    |23/7/2016| 8            |  
CURRENT OUTPUT

EAMEID | EAMDATE | ABSENTDAYS   |  
------ | --------| -------------|
161    |20/7/2016| 1            | 
161    |20/7/2016| 0.5          |   
161    |21/7/2016| 1            |   
161    |22/7/2016| 0            |   
161    |23/7/2016| 0.5          | 

WANTED RESULT 

EAMEID | EAMDATE | ABSENTDAYS   |  
------ | --------| -------------|
161    |20/7/2016| 0.5          |   
161    |21/7/2016| 1            |   
161    |22/7/2016| 0            |   
161    |23/7/2016| 0.5          |
```

Comment: Sample data and expected result.. Looks like a tricky question to me

Comment: Hello, i have added the needed information, waiting for your comment,, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it is not clear (for me) what's your needs.
For example the logic that you need to apply to have

```
EAMEID | EAMDATE | ABSENTDAYS   |  
------ | --------| -------------|
161    |20/7/2016| 0.5          |
```

Starting from

```
EAMEID | EAMDATE | EAMATTNSTATUS| 
------ | --------| -------------|
161    |20/7/2016| 6            | 
161    |20/7/2016| 7            |
```

I mean... why ABSENTDAYS is 0.5 and not 1 ? What's the logic you need to apply to the query?

Comment: when empoyee falls under category 8 or 7 means he has one punch on that day. and i want to count that he is only absent of half day. where is the current output shows that he is absent for 1.5 on that date which is not logical... hope that helps

Comment: Sorry not helps. I still not understand what' the logic needed for your query.
You have 2 records for same user ( 161 ) and same day ( 20/7/2016 )  with different EAMATTNSTATUS 6  and 7.
6=1 (ABSENTDAYS) and 7 = 0.5 (ABSENTDAYS) but:
What's the query logic you need to apply to chose between 1 and 0.5 
It's not clear.
For the day 20/7/2016 and the user 161 how to chose between 0.5 or 1 considering that there are those two values?

Answer (score 0):

You can use your query as sub query and then group.

```
SELECT EAMEMID, EAMDATE, MIN(ABSENTDAYS) MINABSENT FROM  (SELECT EAMEMID,EAMDATE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN EAMATTNSTATUS in (7) OR EAMATTNSTATUS in (8) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / 2 + COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN EAMATTNSTATUS in (6) THEN EAMDATE END) as ABSENTDAYS  
FROM viewDAILYSUM  
WHERE (EAMEMID = :EAMEMID) AND
      (EAMDATE between :FDate and :TDate)
GROUP BY EAMEMID                                                                                                 
ORDER BY EAMEMID)
GROUP BY EAMEMID, EAMDATE
```

Comment: I changed sql. Pls now check.